# print() not working within reactive function

Tags: r, shiny

I typically use `print` when I'm building shinyapps as a way to check to make sure what I *think* should happen is actually what is happening. However, I've run into a problem where `print` is no longer printing to the R console when I have an app running. Here's a simple example of what I've tried:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("slider", "Slider Range",
          min = 0, max = 5000, value = c(11))
)

server <- function(input, output){
  print("Non-Reactive")  
  new <- reactive({
    print("Reactive")
    print(input$slider)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Within the R console, I get: `[1] "Non-Reactive"` and that is it. No `[1] "Reactive"` or `[1] 11` for my slider.

I know it used to work before, but I'm not sure what changed. If there's another easier way to check/debug code for shinyapps aside from `print` I'd love to know my other options too.

Note: My shinyapp package is version 0.13.0. My RStudio version is 0.99.491. R is currently 3.2.2.

Comment: an object is reactive if the code that builds it calls a widget value.

Comment: In this case, the print(input$slider) is calling from a widget value, right?

Comment: Well, that did it. So what does observe() do to cause it to finally print stuff? Can you think of why it would've worked previously without observe but now doesn't?

Thanks for the quick solution!

Comment: Ohh. So if I had `print(input$slider)` on any other type of shiny function (like `renderPrint`) it would have done it? Maybe I've somehow avoided using `print()` when verifying things before.

Answer (score 2):

As jenesaisquoi mentioned, I had to use `observe(new())` later in my server code in order to observe changes in the `reactive()` function. I must just by dumb luck never used `print()` in a `reactive()` function when testing things.